# If $( ax+ 2)( bx+ 7) = 15 x^2 + cx + 14$ for all values of $x$, and $a + b =8$, what are the two possible values for $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please solve the following problem and show your work:

If $(ax + 2)( bx + 7) = 15 x^2 + cx + 14$  for all values of $x$, and $a + b =8$, what are the two possible values for $c$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(ax + 2)(bx + 7) = 15x^2 + cx + 14$$
$$abx^2 + 7ax + 2bx + 14 = 15x^2 + cx + 14$$
Equating coefficients yields:
$$ab = 15$$
$$7a + 2b = c$$
But $a + b = 8$.  Therefore $a$ and $b$ are roots of the quadratic equation:
$$y^2 - 8y + 15 = 0$$
$$(y - 5)(y - 3) = 0$$
Therefore, either $(a, b) = (3, 5)$ or $(a, b) = (5, 3)$.

Hence, either 
$$c = 7(3) + 2(5) = 31$$
or
$$c = 7(5) + 2(3) = 41.$$

Answer (score 0):

First we can expand the left hand side:

\begin{align}(ax+2)(bx+7)&=15x^2+cx+14\\
abx^2+2bx+7ax+14&=15x^2+cx+14\\
abx^2+(7a+2b)x+14&=15x^2+cx+14\end{align}

We can equate coefficients to see that

\begin{align}ab&=15\tag{$x^2$}\\
7a+2b&=c\tag{$x$}\end{align}

We can say that \begin{align}a+b&=8\\a&=8-b\end{align}

And thus \begin{align}ab&=15\\
(8-b)b&=15\\
8b-b^2&=15\\
b^2-8b+15&=0\\
(b-5)(b-3)&=0\end{align}

So we can say $b=3$ or $b=5$

When $b=3$, then $a=5$ and we can say that

\begin{align}c&=7a+2b\\
&=7\times 5+2\times 3\\
&= 35+6\\
&= 41\end{align}

When $b=5$, then $a=3$ and we can say that

\begin{align}c&=7a+2b\\
&=7\times 3+2\times 5\\
&= 21+10\\
&= 31\end{align}

So, the two values of $c$ are $41$ and $31$

Answer (score -2):

It’s a simple problem. Just focus on the problem. You will find it easy.
[image]